# regex expression in java What will be the regex in java for a birth date whose age should be 70 years on a present day

Tags: java

regex expression in java
What will be the regex in java for a birth date whose age should be 70 years on a present day

Comment: Parse it as a proper date object and use some properly written date comparisons to check that logic, do NOT use regex for such a thing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that you are supposed to search before asking a question here and when you post a question, tell us what your search brought up and specify how it fell short of solving your problem. It’s for your own sake since (1) you often find a better answer faster that way (2) it allows us to give preciser and more focused answers. It also tends to prevent or at least reduce the number of downvotes.

Comment: Should the birthday fall on the present date? Or is it enough that that person has reached 70 years and not yet 71 years of age?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions is NOT the right tool here.

Use `java.time` to parse dates, and compare them to the reference date of 70 years ago that you will previously compute.

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class BirthdayParser {

  //Your date format as a pattern
  private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //Date format
    final DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    
    //Reference date
    final LocalDate d70YearsAgo = LocalDate.now().minusYears(70);
   
    //Test all supplied dates
    for (String testDate: testDates) {
      LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse(testDate, df);
      boolean is70thBirthday = parsed.equals(d70YearsAgo);
      System.out.println(testDate + " -> " + is70thBirthday);
    }
    
  }
  
  //tests in given date format
  private static final String[] testDates = {
    "2020-05-18", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-19",
    "1950-05-18", "1950-05-17", "1950-05-19",
    "1951-05-18", "1951-05-17", "1951-05-19",
  };
  
}
```

This will output (considering we're on 2021-05-18):

```
2020-05-18 -> false
2020-05-17 -> false
2020-05-19 -> false
1950-05-18 -> false
1950-05-17 -> false
1950-05-19 -> false
1951-05-18 -> true
1951-05-17 -> false
1951-05-19 -> false
```